# Multiple multivariate normal density values in R and Rcpp

Tags: r

I have a question concerning a fast implementation. Imagine that you have a matrix Ys in which each row refers to a vector of observed values stemming from a multivariate normal distribution, e.g.,

```
    Ys = matrix(c(1.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,0.5,0.6,0.1,0.1,0.3), nrow = 3, ncol = 3)
```

Furthermore, there is a matrix Sigs in which each row refers to the diagonal elements of the variance covariance matrix for each of the outcome vectors in Ys, e.g.,

```
    Sigs = matrix(c(1.0,0.5,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.3,0.7,0.8), nrow = 3, ncol = 3)
```

What I want to do is to compute the density value of each row in Ys given the diagonal elemnts in the respective row in Sigs.

One could use a for-loop in R, e.g.

```
    colSigs = ncol(Sigs)
    res = rep(0,3)
    means = rep(0,colSigs)
    for (i in 1:nrow(Ys) ) {
            sigma = diag(Sigs[i,],colSigs)
            res[i] = mvtnorm::dmvnorm(Ys[i,],means,sigma)
    }
```

however, in my case Ys and Sigs contain about 100,000 rows. So I wrote an Rcpp-function that is considerably faster. Nevertheless, I was wondering whether there is a fancy trick (a more efficient way) so that I do not have to do looping? Any ideas are welcome.

## ----

EDIT: I was asked to add the Rcpp functions. Here, you go:

This function computes the quadratic form appearing in the multivariate normal density:

```
double dmvnorm_distance( arma::rowvec y, arma::mat Sigma )
    {
    int n = Sigma.n_rows;
    double res=0;
    double fac=1;
    for (int ii=0; ii<n; ii++){
        for (int jj=ii; jj<n; jj++){
            if (ii==jj){ fac = 1; } else { fac = 2;}
            res += fac *y(0,ii) * Sigma(ii,jj) * y(0,jj);
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

This function computes the density value:

double dmvnorm_rcpp( arma::rowvec y, arma::mat Sigma )
    {

```
    int p = Sigma.n_rows;

    // inverse Sigma
    arma::mat Sigma1 = arma::inv(Sigma);
    // determinant Sigma
    double det_Sigma = arma::det(Sigma);
    // distance
    double dist = dmvnorm_distance( y, Sigma1);

    double pi1 = 3.14159265358979;
    double l1 = - p * std::log(2*pi1) - dist - std::log( det_Sigma );
    double ll = 0.5 * l1;

    return ll;
}
```

and this function contains the for-loop and is called from R:

```
Rcpp::NumericVector mvnorm_loop( arma::mat Ys, arma::mat SIGs )
{
    int n = Ys.n_rows;
    Rcpp::NumericVector out(n);

    for (int ii=0; ii<n; ii++){

         // get yi and diagonal entries
         arma::rowvec yi = Ys.row(ii);
         arma::rowvec si = SIGs.row(ii);; 

         // make Sigma
         arma::mat Sigma = arma::diagmat(si);

         // compute likelihood value       
         out[ii] = dmvnorm_rcpp( yi, Sigma );
    }

    return out;
}
```

So basically the question is whether there is an alternative way to implement the insertion in Rcpp to make the whole thing even more faster.

## ----

Best,
Stefan

PS: I also used apply in R and it is slower than the Rcpp loop-function.

Comment: Could you provide the Rcpp code to let me test how fast it is?

Comment: I have added the code. Any help is appreciated! Best Stefan